# Connect to windows shared using IP address in SMB

Tags: python, smb, shared-drive

I need to connect to Windows shared drive in Python, and for that I'm using the `pysmb` library.

The code I have used is as follows:

```
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection

username = "username@domain.com"
password = "password"
client_machine_name = "any_name"
hostname = "server_20xx"
ip_address = "10.10.xxx.xx"

# Create the connection object
conn = SMBConnection(username, password, client_machine_name, 
       host_name, use_ntlm_v2=True)

# Connect to the server
conn.connect(host_name, 139)
```

Since the UNC can be either `\\ip_address\share_name` or `\\hostname\share_name`,  why doesn't the smb client accept ip_address for establishing a connection?

When I use

```
conn = SMBConnection(username, password, client_machine_name, 
       ip_address, use_ntlm_v2=True)
conn.connect(ip_address, 139)
```

The error returned is

```
raise NotConnectedError
smb.base.NotConnectedError
```

Comment: Please provide a working example. We cannot see, what your variables actually contain. You can, of course, obfuscate username and password or leave them out entirely, but you are asking about the host, so what is in the `ip_address` and `host_name` variables?

Comment: Added the variables

Comment: pysmb includes a `NetBIOS.queryIPForName` method that can find the machine name for a given IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following parameter 'is_direct_tcp=True' on SMBConnection method and change connection port from 139 to 445:

```
conn = SMBConnection(username, password, client_machine_name, 
   ip_address, use_ntlm_v2=True, is_direct_tcp=True)
conn.connect(ip_address, 445)
```

Comment: The `ip_address` variable is already a string.  Did you not see that?